# Create Multiple Plots for time series using dplyr in R

Tags: r, plot, dplyr

I have multiple sites that I sample multiple times (different dates) with which I run time-series experiments to obtain a value for each time point in that series (for each site there are 4 time points). I would like to graph each time series (`Time..hours.`) (x-axis) versus their values (`Sample.N2O.gas...ppm.`)(y-axis) for each site for its respective date and have multiple plots to view all this data at once.

I'm new to R, so I'm not sure if attaching the image of my data is helpful or not. [Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lo5LG.png)

What I've found so far is:

```
  plots <- data %>% group_by(Site, Date, Treatment, Rep) %>% do(plots=ggplot(data=.)) +
  aes(x=Time..hours., y=Sample.N2O.gas...ppm.) + geom_point()
```

but when I run plots, I just get an output table '#A Tibble 149x5".

Here's what I've copied from my dput output:

```
   data = structure(list(Site = structure(c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("QA1", "QA1 ", 
"QA2", "W1", "W2", "W3", "W4"), class = "factor"), Date = structure(c(1462860000, 
1462860000, 1462860000, 1462860000, 1462860000, 1462860000, 1462860000, 
1462860000, 1462860000, 1462860000, 1462860000, 1462860000, 1462860000, 
1462860000, 1462860000, 1462860000, 1462860000, 1462860000, 1462860000, 
1462860000, 1462860000, 1462860000, 1462860000, 1462860000, 1462860000, 
1462860000, 1462860000, 1462860000, 1462860000, 1462860000, 1462860000, 
1462860000), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), Treatment = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Control", 
"DEA", "Denit"), class = "factor"), Rep = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), Time..hours. = c(0.333333333, 
1.166666667, 2, 2.833333333, 0.333333333, 1.166666667, 2, 2.833333333, 
0.333333333, 1.166666667, 2, 2.833333333, 0.333333333, 1.166666667, 
2, 2.833333333, 0.333333333, 1.166666667, 2, 2.833333333, 0.333333333, 
1.166666667, 2, 2.833333333, 0.333333333, 1.166666667, 2, 2.833333333, 
0.333333333, 1.166666667, 2, 2.833333333), Sample.N2O.gas...ppm. = c(0.02536993437111, 
0.02539270198174, 0.0258252865837, 0.02236460976796, 0.01136785383374, 
0.00886341666446, 0.01291605135657, 0.01583030551719, 0.05517273668559, 
0.15960776664476, 0.12206397671612, 0.10999714308229, 0.08618222236346, 
0.062344534034, 0.0527366023482, 0.05845127261629, 0.03570642959706, 
0.05093796110844, 0.04784156606278, 0.05763163863362, 24.1815481999959, 
43.9535598867979, 76.0087551511654, 97.5847143861169, 26.1044322512172, 
42.2811119155545, 82.8088875655402, 109.127381921808, 24.9257144556248, 
46.2630281688243, 84.5042194191463, 102.597585589484)), .Names = c("Site", 
"Date", "Treatment", "Rep", "Time..hours.", "Sample.N2O.gas...ppm."
), row.names = c(NA, 32L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Instead of showing a picture of your data, use `dput` to turn your data into something you can share.  This will help us help you.

Comment: Is this better? Sorry for my noobness

Comment: Perfect.  Does my answer make sense?

Comment: When I run 'plots[[1]] ' I just get a list of my sites

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you've created a list of plots (technically a tibble of plots).  To view the first plot in the list, say, you'll need to do `plots[[1]]`

*Addendum:*  Actually, your code in its current form doesn't quite work.  Did you mean to do the following?

```
plots <- data %>% group_by(Site, Date, Treatment, Rep) %>% do(plots=ggplot(data=.) +
    aes(x=Time..hours., y=Sample.N2O.gas...ppm.) + geom_point())
```

If so, then (strangely), the plots are buried in a list called plots.  You can access the first one with `plots$plots[[1]]`, and show all of them by just going `plots$plots`.

Comment: Is there a quick way to add a title that will fit each individual graph? When I look at each graph I'm not sure which sample I'm looking at until I look at the data.